# How to create new input text using a select with values in form using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function updateItems() {
  const data = {
  ItemNames: []
  };
  var ItemCount = document.getElementById("selectQty").value;
  for (var i = 1; i <= ItemCount; i++){
    data.ItemLists.push({
      id: `ItemName${i}`,
      value: document.getElementById(`ItemName${i}`).value
    });
  }
}
```

Above is my code, I am trying to create new input text called id="ItemName" to create based on the value in the select combobox called id="selectQty". I created this loop but it doesn't create new input text based on the selected number in the combo box. I am beginner at Javascript and doing exercises. I tried looking for other solution but I can't seem to find any. Any help will be appreciated.

This function will be called on using the select:

```
<select id="selectQty" onchange="updateItems()">
  <option value="0" disabled selected value>Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  <option value="2">4</option>
  <option value="2">5</option>
  <option value="2">6</option>
  <option value="2">7</option>
</select>
```

This is my input text

```
<input type="text" id="ItemName" placeholder="Item Name">
```

Comment: use createElement() for creating new elements to the DOM. please refer to this documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Comment: Couple of things here `data` has a property named `ItemNames`, but you are pushing data into it's `ItemLists` array. And, where is the code for adding input fields?

Comment: Try using `innnerHTML` method to insert the `<input>` string template into the html

Comment: `selectQty` is not the id of `membership-members`....

Comment: Are you trying to create new inputs when you select the qty from the options ? If yes! where do you want those input to appear OR You want to store them in an array ?

Comment: When I select a qty from the options, I want the input to appear. So If i select 4 from the options then 4 inputs should show on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method to create new dynamically added inputs.

To get the value of actual input we need to create we can use `_this.value` which will be coming from our `onclick` function.

You might notice this `+` sign which mean we are converting the `string` number to actual `integer` format for looping purposes.

Also, i have also added`label` to each of your input when they are created you can name the `label` to what `suits` you the best.

In addition, to make it look nicer we can add line break `<br>` to make sure our labels and input are generated in `each` line.

Lastly, you need to use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to make sure that you set the `results` to empty each time you `select` a different `option` from the select.

You can also refer to each `comment` as well i have added in each line of `JS` code below.

**Live Demo:**

```js
function updateItems(_this) {
  var ItemCount = +_this.value //get the value
  var results = document.querySelector('#results') //append results
  results.innerHTML = '' //clear the results on each update
  for (var i = 1; i <= ItemCount; i++) {
    var input = document.createElement('input') //create input
    var label = document.createElement("label"); //create label
    label.innerText = 'Input ' + i
    input.type = "text";
    input.placeholder = "Type text here"; //add a placeholder
    input.className = "my-inputs"; // set the CSS class
    results.appendChild(label); //append label
    results.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    results.appendChild(input); //append input
    results.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="membership-members" onchange="updateItems(this)">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, first time seeing createElement

Comment: @stewieranger124 You are welcome. happy coding. Please consider upvotting my answer as well by clicking the grey upvote arrow in my answer. thank you :)